# Drupal - Node Delete Button and Node Expiration Date

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-nodes

In Drupal 7 when a user is logged in and viewing their own node, or an admin is viewing any node I'm looking to have 2 buttons that appear:

1. Delete NODE
2. Renew NODE

When delete is pressed, the status is set and then saved.
When Renew is pressed, the expiration date is extended by another 30 days.

Any advice on how to get started is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://drupal.org/project/auto_expire or http://drupal.org/project/scheduler module for node renew option , i hope it will help you!!!.